# How to get all users with a role in Discord.js in a array

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get all the members with a certain role. For example, there is role of gurdian in my discord server with a id of 872029521484873779. I want a list of all the users Name in a array who have gurdian as a role in my server. My code is as below

```
let nameList= msg.guild.roles.cache.get('role_id').members.map(m=>m.user.tag);
```

However, In result it only returns one user in the `nameList` whereas as there are 9 users with the role assigned to them. What am I doing wrong here which is bringing me only 1 user not the rest of 9 users in a list in array. I am new to discord.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the members aren't cached. So you only see 1 person logging because only 1 person is in the cache. To fix this, you can fetch all members by doing `msg.guild.members.fetch()`, then use `msg.guild.roles.cache.get("roleid").members.map(m => m.user.tag)` to get the real output. Please do note that you will need the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent if you are on v13.

Fetching members from the guild will store them in cache. So when you do do `role.members`, you get the members who have this role.

If you don't fetch members, then the info won't be accurate. Discord.js stores users in cache. This happens whenever someone sends a message, updates their profile or anything about themselves **WHILE the bot is online**. So if you restart your bot, no one will be in the cache.

Why is fetch different from cache?

Fetch gets the info directly from discord, while cache is checking if the user is stored locally. When you fetch members, they are automatically stored in the cache as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on how would msg.guild.members.fetch would help you in getting the user id in next code line of msg.guild ?? I am very new here and could not understand how it will work? Could you show the exact implementation of it.

Comment: Fetching members from the guild will store them in cache. So when you do do role.members, you get the members who have this role.

If you don't fetch members, then the info won't be accurate. Discord.js stores users in cache. This happens whenever someone sends a message, updates their profile or anything about themselves WHILE the bot is online. So if you restart your bot, no one will be in the cache.

Fetch gets the info directly from discord, while cache is checking if the user is stored locally. When you fetch members, they are automatically stored in the cache as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I am going to mark it as  correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake might be a simple confusion with the id numbers. The number in your code is different then the number in your question

Comment: Yea, I also think this might be the case because I tested their code on my own server and it's working just fine with my role IDs

Comment: nah it is not that I made it to test out but it was not this issue which is what making me wonder. I will though correct it in the question now. Thanks