# Discord.js update cache to pull all members that have role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Currently having issues pulling all members that have a certain role. I can currently pull a list of names but only those that are cached currently. If i leave my bot running for a few hrs it will pull more but it never pulls all members that have that role. Ive read a few different things about using the .fetch() command but still no dice.

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ]
});


msg.channel.send('exporting all members with delcared role');

msg.guild.roles.fetch('guildId');//cache roles i think?
let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Sysadmins');


msg.guild.members.fetch('roleId');//cache members i think?
let list = msg.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members.map(m => m.nickname)

console.log(role);
console.log(list);
```

The console.log(); returns my nickname as expected but only mine and i know there are at least 10 others with this role.

Other questions similar that I have already tried:

[Similar Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304341/discord-js-get-all-members-that-have-a-specific-role)

[Similar Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911795/how-to-get-all-users-with-a-role-in-discord-js-in-a-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DanLop your answer along with @MrMythical and a few other stack overflow questions helped me get this one sovled. I was able to use the async functions properly to pull all the data i need below is what i ended up with.

Solution:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async msg => {  //TODO here });

let list = client.guilds.cache.get(tempGuildId);

try {
    await list.members.fetch();

    let role1 = list.roles.cache.get(roleId).members.map(m => m.displayName);
    console.log(role1);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're giving the **fetch()** method a String argument, only the user matched with that String will be fetched, more like a **get()**. Also, the **fetch()** method returns a Promise, which means the method must be awaited to actually recieve the data.

Your **fetch()** method should look like this:

```js
await msg.guild.members.fetch();
```

This way you tell Node.js it must wait until you recieve the data promised before continue.

Comment: the await doesnt seem to be the problem, it seems i need to set the data inside the fetch()

Comment: The await is actually the problem, if you see [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) it tells you the way to fetch all members. Also, it tells you the fetch() method returns a Promise.

Comment: I just looked at your GitHub repo. The way you're trying to fetch() with the return await makes no difference at all. To make it work try this in your event first: `client.on('messageCreate', async msg => { 
//TODO here }); `. Then just use the `await msg.guild.members.fetch();` method.

Comment: Alright so i updated what you suggested and i found a way to grab all members but it turns out getting all members of a specific role i need to do another way.

Answer (score 0):

It's close, but much simpler, with 3 lines

```js
await msg.guild.members.fetch() // fetch all members and cache them
const role = msg.guild.roles.cache.get("id") // get role from cache by ID (roles are always cached)
const list = role.members.map(m => m.nickname) // map members by nickname
```

Comment: This still seems to only be pulling just my name for the role

Comment: @djbears32 do you have GUILD_MEMBERS intent?

Comment: see update question

Comment: Can you log msg.guild.members.cache.size?

Comment: hmmm first time i run the command i get one response. If i run it again shortly after i get a bigger list but the list included members not from the desired role

Comment: Can you try sending a sourcebin of your new code?

Comment: This command:
console.log(msg.guild.members.cache.size);
returns 2

Comment: Do you have GUILD_MEMBERS intent enabled in developer portal?

Comment: How about a github link?

Comment: Yes i have that as well i can send you more information through discord?

Comment: GitHub might be good, guess I would be able to see more of your code

Comment: You need to await the getMembers function

Comment: I only added the async function because i couldnt do just
await msg.guild.members.fetch()
without it throwing an error

Comment: You have to make the callback async, return await does nothing different than return

Comment: I must not be understanding async functions let me do a little research to fully understand what you mean